# In Star Trek: Into Darkness, What is Bones' serum (SPOILER)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

> At the end of the movie Bones creates a serum from Khan's blood which he uses to revive Kirk. Do they now have the ability to cure all disease and even short term death? They could start harvesting Kahn's race for blood. It was a big enough temptation for one man to kill in order to save his daughter imagine the possibility of being able to eliminate death.

Comment: Seems so odd to have the entire question into spoiler tags...

Comment: Serum could mean just be blood serum which is just blood plasma.

Comment: @Kalissar Maybe I am being overly cautious about what a spoiler is.

Comment: I think that most questions of the new Star Trek movies can only be answered with "that's the plot". I'd be **very** surprised if this is ever mentioned again.

Comment: McCoy's serum is actually William Shatner's blood. As such, it has the ability to cure any disease, male pattern baldness, and hangovers.

Comment: Tip:  He says exactly what the serum is made of when he first injects the tribble.  It's not a direct blood-blood transfusion.  I can't quite remember what it was, though...

Comment: @Izkata - it's platelets from Khan's blood

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for the effect of the serum, it look like it could cure any disease. McCoy also literally revived a dead [Tribble](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tribble) with a simple blood sample. However, they had to freeze Kirk in order to preserve his brain function; that is the only limitation we are made aware of. The other details about how it works and its effectiveness are unknown.

As for the nature of Bones's serum, given that a girl was cured using unaltered blood, the serum could be literally a substrate of Khan's blood. So the simple, but somewhat unethical solution, would be to use the frozen members of Khan's race to produce serum from their blood.

Since Tribbles are an alien species, it may mean it's not a property of the blood itself, but it may be an additive in the blood that cause the regeneration. From that point, Bones may have found a way to synthesize this additive, allowing its production from scratch.

With all that known, an elegant solution would be to create a *race* of genetically enhanced Tribbles that would be used to mass produce that serum. But nothing in the movie indicates it's McCoy's solution.

Comment: Create a race of immortal, unkillable tribbles, you say?  What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @jwodder I, for one, welcome our new genetically enhanced Tribbles overlords!

Comment: Disclaimer: no tribbles were hurt in the making of this film.

Comment: Another question that arises from this; they have to remove one of Khan's race from the cryotube to put Kirk into it. Why couldn't that member's blood have done the same?

Comment: They'll have to find limits or drawbacks to it, no?

Comment: @KeithS Good point, that would also imply that they either re-animated one of the frozen crewmen, or simply killed it through improper revival to bring Kirk back.

Comment: @Monty129 - Well actually, Bones said to keep the crewmember in an induced coma, so we know he never woke up. The question remains why that crewman's blood wouldn't have the same effect as Khan's.

Comment: @KeithS What do you wait to ask this question?

Comment: @KeithS [Someone asked it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36503/why-did-mccoy-need-khan-to-revive-kirk)